# Weird inpropper faces clipping

Tags: faces, clipping

[image]

I have this werid issue were the Flat Plane goes through the mesh diffrently on both sides even tho both of those side are mirrors of each other. Any way to fix this? The issue seems to begin with the corner Faces.
I have tried making using diffrent methods to fix this issue and have the same looking lines on both sides but nothing works. The futher the Plane goes from the starter vertice the bigger the "error" becomes.

Subdivision for the Planes does nothing and for the mesh the subdivision makes the "error" "round up" so instead of flat surfaces I get round ones wich is even worse.

Comment: Hi. You might have better luck getting an answer if you could upload your .blend file, or if it is too big, one with the problem parts in it to: https://blend-exchange.com/ Otherwise, adding some more images to your question to more clearly show the problem.

Comment: It seems like it has to do with the faces of your mesh not being planar, and the triangulation being different on the two supposedly mirrored sides.

Comment: Yea the triangulation was being a jerk to me had to apply it manually thanks for the info quellenform.